# On setting the image as featured image, it cuts on preview in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am facing a issue regarding featured image in a post... What i am doing is showing the featured image in the post... But when i set image as a featured image it cuts down in preview also in main webpage...

**Image i have uploaded:-**

[image: Image i have uploaded]

**On setting it as a featured image:-**

[image: On setting it as a featured image]

**Screenshot of adminpanel:-**

[image]

**Screenshot of Mainpage post:-**

[image]

I seriously dont know the reason for this, it happens with every image i set for it...

Comment: that is because of your theme setting that probably cuts it that way.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen want i have to do for this to avoid this cutoff...

Comment: if you know your code ,you just have to use `set_post_thumbnail_size( 575, 100, true )` - or check the size that is specified in the theme .

Comment: ya i found this code on functions.php.. `set_post_thumbnail_size( $custom_header_support['width'], $custom_header_support['height'], true );`

Comment: that means that the theme is taking the height and width from the custom header options .. Just change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw in the comment your code is :

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( $custom_header_support['width'], $custom_header_support['height'], true );
```

"True" parameter means it allows the code to crop you image.

I suggest you to make a new thumbnail size via :
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-sizes/

After this you can directly call your thumbnail size in code like this :

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('custom-thumbnail-size'); ?>
```

"custom-thumbnail-size" is the name you give to your size in the plugin.

CF: http://www.bernskiold.com/2011/08/08/adding-custom-image-size-post-thumbnails-wordpress/
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Answer (score 1):

@Zekth has given you the answer :-)

You just need to create a new custom thumbnail or edit existing one in functions page.

In functions.php just add

```
 <?php set_post_thumbnail_size( $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

if you set crop true, then it will crop the image, otherwise it will just resize the image while maintaining aspect ratio.

Or create a new thumbnail size

```
add_image_size( 'new-thumb', 220, 180, true ); //(cropped)
```

and use it in appropriate page.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'new-thumb' );
```

you can set crop to true and false on order to achieve cropped image or to maintain aspect ratio..

Source of knowledge : 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: your code is also upto the mark, it also helped me in finding the solution thanks for your time...